# strip identifier from result of .toString() method

Tags: java, react-native

It is out of desperation and I don't know java. Basically, I want to resolve a couchbase lite [Document](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.7/java-platform.html#document) back to a react-native application as follows:

```
       Document doc = database.getDocumet('id');
       promise.resolve(doc);
```

that doesn't work with error can't be cast so I turned to toString(), hoping to parse it in react-native:

```
      promise.resolve(doc.toString());
```

// in js:

```
      const document = getNativeDocument('id');
      console.log(document)
      const v = JSON.parse(document);
```

but that fails too with error:

```
        SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Document"].
```

The console result is:

```
Document{@0xb3181c18e30a7f1-1f61-49a0-9ca0-1dc3d2e343ed@1-a7ed608736c34cf5860a0d35968e6441e1f089ef(..):obj=>Dictionary{(..)a=>A,b=>B},age=>20,firstPromo=>null}
```

I have tried solutions to convert the Document into other times that can easily be resolved by promise.resolve() but now wondering if there is away to work with results of the .toString()

Answer (score 0):

the `toString` method generates an internal representation of the object for debugging, not JSON of the document. You need to use a different method to serialize your Document to JSON.

The most popular option for this is to use the Jackson library: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

If you're using Spring framework with Spring data couchbase connector then Jackson's ObjectMapper should already be available to your application as a Bean.